# Windows Web Server 2008 R2  is sufficient for IIS , FTP , website and Frontpage installation?

Tags: web-server

Would Windows Web Server 2008 R2 be sufficient for following

1)IIS
2)FTP site publication
3)Remote Website(Can I have a remote website and a FTP site on the same server)
4)Frontpage (can i install it on the Server)

thanks

Comment: Frontpage? Why why why why why \*head desk\*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. Yes
4. Where are you getting Frontpage from?

Comment: I realize now that FrontPage is already a feature in IIS , and I will have to simply enable it ,Please let me know if im wrong here

Comment: http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=2035 this website says that i could download it individually too .. what would be the preffered option ..

Comment: Hmm... I thought Frontpage was dead but if the download is available, and you need it, I say go ahead.

Comment: thanks a lot Joe .. !  the whole intention behind this was to have an application upgrade automatically using Microsoft ClickOnce Deployment .. All these played an important part in that regard .

Comment: Glad to help...